# Nagios, plugin to get cassandra row count

Tags: cassandra, single-sign-on, nagios, cqlsh, nrpe

Is there a plugin for Nagios which I can use to get the row count of a Cassandra table for a specified limit.

I am up for an alternate approach as well:-

I can hit an API Endpoint which is already giving the above result but this API needs OAuth authorization. So I need to perform following steps:-

> 1. Hit a Sign in API and get an access token.
> 2. Store this in a variable and use it to hit the above endpoint.
> 3. Get the response and decide the critical/warning/ok message.